# How do I stop virbr0 interface being created?

Tags: 16.04, internet, network-bridge

Whenever I start my laptop(HP) , 'Network Connections' shows it being connected (though it is actually not) . When I go to 'edit connections' option , it shows **virbr0** . I have to delete it every time . How to get rid of this ? Is it a hardware problem ?

Comment: Are you running any VMs like VirtualBox or VMPlayer?  If you are, virbr0 is created by those and should not be removed.

Comment: No . I'm not using any of them . @Terrance

Comment: Sorry, I only listed 2 of them.  There is a bigger list [here of VMs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualMachines).   Any VM that is installed will create that for the virtual bridged network so the VM will get IP addresses.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On my machine **virbr0** interface was created after installation of `libvirt-bin` package which is dependency of `virt-manager`.

**Solution 1** (straight-forward):

It seems you can remove it from startup by removing corresponding file with

```
sudo rm /etc/libvirt/qemu/networks/autostart/default.xml
```

You can bring it back with

```
sudo ln -s /etc/libvirt/qemu/networks/default.xml /etc/libvirt/qemu/networks/autostart/default.xml
```

**Solution 2** (with `virsh`)

- disable: `sudo virsh net-autostart --disable default`
- enable: `sudo virsh net-autostart default`

But this has side-effect. If you want to use bridged network in virt-manager you should start bridge before launching VM with `sudo virsh net-start default`.

**Solution 3** (set **virbr0** unmanaged in NetworkManager)

The following lines should be added to the end of */etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf*:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:virbr0
```

The result: NetworkManager "does not know" about **virbr0**, but VMs can access bridged networking.

Comment: I added the same lines as the third solution to /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf but it's still there. Will that take effect after restarting the system?

Answer (score 2):

Give this a [try this](http://itrepo.com/remove-virbr0-interface-linux/) is mostly for Centos

```
sudo su -
virsh net-destroy default
virsh net-undefine default
systemctl stop libvirtd.service
systemctl disable libvirtd.service
apt remove qemu-kvm qemu-img virt-manager libvirt libvirt-python libvirt-client virt-install virt-viewer bridge-utils
```

Comment: Please [read this](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) about how to write a good answer, particularly the section "Provide context for links". Also: Did you successfully tried this on Ubuntu?

Comment: It works in Ubuntu Server 22.