# How do I disable network manager permanently?

Tags: network-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. I want to disable network manager on an Ubuntu machine, because (1) I don't need it, (2) I prefer having hardcoded configuration, and (3) network manager regularly causes issues by changing the DHCP configuration.

I tried to follow [the official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager#Stopping_and_Disabling_NetworkManager):

> Stop network manager
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
> ```
>
> Disable network manager (permanently) to avoid it restarting after a reboot
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager.service
> ```

Despite this, the network manager is back again every time I reboot the machine.

How can I make it go away?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot simply uninstall NM?

Comment: What do you want to use instead of NetworkManager - netplan as [in server](https://help.ubuntu.com/18.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A290%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C54%2C769.889%2Cnull%5D)?

Comment: @user535733: I didn't know network manager can be uninstalled. I'll check this one.

Comment: @N0rbert: just hardcoded configuration in /etc/network/interfaces and in /etc/resolv.conf. Don't know if there is an official name for that.

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko What is your desktop environment? If it is GNOME, then purging network-manager will remove gnome-control-center, which is essential part of GNOME.

Comment: I can't link questions on here I believe this is (indirectly?) related to my question https://askubuntu.com/questions/938062/prevent-network-manager-controlling-rndis-interfaces the common theme being "how can I prevent network manager taking over things that I don't want it to"

Comment: @N0rbert: Try apt-holepunch (https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?att=1;bug=625801;filename=apt-holepunch;msg=29) by me from debian bug #625801 (https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=625801).

Comment: Find Lennart Poettering and chop off his fingers in case he ever tries to write any more software. Systemd: a disaster (but you can sort of understand where that comes from). Pulseaudio, eugh, open a web browser it changes your system audio limits, close it it changes it again open mplayer it changes it again. Then there's network manager, what does network manager actually offer apart from a confusing extra layer of garbage that sits on top of ifconfig?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The method depends on desktop environment:

- For Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS and 20.04 LTS purging `network-manager` package is safe. You can simply run:

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge network-manager
  ```
- For Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and 20.04 LTS with GNOME desktop purging `network-manager` package will also purge `ubuntu-desktop` and `gnome-control-center` (essential part of GNOME desktop). So it is not an option.

  Here you should disable NetworkManager service (as you have already done):

  ```
  sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
  sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager.service
  ```

  and three more services:

  ```
  sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager-wait-online.service
  sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service

  sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
  sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager-dispatcher.service

  sudo systemctl stop network-manager.service
  sudo systemctl disable network-manager.service
  ```

  and then reboot.

---

Notes:

1. You can read more about network configuration with `/etc/network/interfaces` from [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A276%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C54%2C769.889%2Cnull%5D).
2. Modern Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server uses `netplan`, you can read about it in the [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/18.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A290%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C54%2C769.889%2Cnull%5D).

Comment: I always purge NetworkManager as one of my first post-install steps -- since at least 14. Perhaps this issue with the removal of the desktop was a bug?

Comment: Not a bug, but dependency issue.

Comment: Has it been resolved? Or is there a difference between our repositories? I have not had the experience you report with purging NM. I have found that some applications assume NM to be installed and active but none of them have been unique or essential.

Comment: For me the issue persists. Tested on minimal 18.04 LTS VM with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop^` followed by `sudo apt-get purge network-manager`.

Comment: How very strange! I had a 19.10 VM that I hadn't played with yet so NM was still installed. I purged it, ran update and upgrade, and the desktop runs perfectly. I saw the upgrade think about upgrading NM but after reboot it is still not installed.

Comment: Thanks N0rbert!  I was recently having issues with my server where every so many days it would just go offline to the internet but work locally just fine.  I would restart the networking service and everything seemed OK.  This actually saved me because I am running `ifupdown` instead of `NetworkManager` and they conflict apparently with each other, so this solved my headaches!  Thanks again!

Comment: FWIW, I think the difference the commenters face is due to different dependency settings. If you have "recommends" set to be installed then "*-desktop" will be "required" preventing removal of it's downstream dependencies.

Answer (score 9):

Try the `mask` command:

```
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
sudo systemctl mask NetworkManager.service
```

> mask NAME...
>
> Mask one or more units, as specified on the command line. This will link these unit files to /dev/null, making it impossible to start them.
>   This is a stronger version of disable, since it prohibits all kinds of activation of the unit, including enablement and manual activation. Use this option with care. This honors the --runtime option to only mask temporarily until the next reboot of the system.
>   The --now option may be used to ensure that the units are also
>          stopped. This command expects valid unit names only, it does not accept unit file paths.